# Thread Execution not complete in a loop

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I need to insert 50000 of records to the Database using 10 threads as 5000 per thread.
Ex. thread 1 will insert 1-5000, thread 2 will insert 5001-10000 etc.

I have use the ExecutorService to do this.

## Code

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
int i=0;
 while(i<vVec.size())
 {
  if(i<vVec.size())
  {
    DBInsertDetail rrr = (DBInsertDetail)vVec.get(i);
    TestThread t1 = new TestThread(rrr);
    threadPool.execute(t1);

  }

  i++;
}


 try {
       threadPool.shutdown();
       boolean bTermination = false;


       while (true) 
       {
     bTermination = threadPool.awaitTermination(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);  

     if(!bTermination)
     {
         Log.debug("Awaiting completion of threads.");
     }
     else
     {
        Log.debug("Threads Completed."+iTermiVal);
        break;
     }

     if(threadPool.isTerminated())
     {
       break;
     }      

     }
 } catch (Exception e) {}
```

## TestThread class

```
public class TestThread implements Runnable 
{
    private volatile DBInsertDetail syncc;

    public Thread1(DBInsertDetail syncc) {
        this.syncc = syncc;        
    }

    public void run() { 

    try  
    {         this.syncc.cardCreProcess(syncc.getIncre(),syncc.getStarterial(),syncc.getCurTblSeq());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {              
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

## DBInsertDetail class

```
public class DBInsertDetail {
public void cardCreProcess(int iNum,int iCurrSerl,int iCurTblSeq)
{
  int iCardCountTest = 0;
  try
  {
   synchronized(this)
   {

    for (int i = 0; i < iNum; i++)
    {
     iCurrSerl++;
     iCurTblSeq++;
     iCardCountTest++;    

     CmnDet stkDet = new CmnDet();
     Data crdData = new Data();
     String sNo = crdData.getNextNo(pro, prof, sBranch, iCurrSerl);

     stkDet.setNo(sNo);
     stkDet.setCod(""+iCurTblSeq);

     if (!stkDet.saveToDataBase(con))
     {
    sErrorMsg +="Error Occured" + "\n";
     }

   }

  }
}catch(Exception ex)
{
ex.printStackTrace();

}
finally{
  //commit and return connection
}

}
}
```

**Problem is this will not execute correctly for larger nos. If increase the records per thread 10000, process runs without any error but inserts only a part of batch. Any idea?**

Comment: You code looks fine. Can you show us vVec initializing and creating of DBInsertDetail instances. I suspect you have problems with `iNum, iCurrSerl, etc`

Comment: why are you sleeping in each thread? Is that some sort of test? It does not look like a useful way to insert a lot of data since all threads have to use the `synchronized` block which means they can't insert in parallel and have to run in sequential order in the end. That would work with just one thread already. Or even 0 threads since your method that starts all the threads does not return before the threads are done.

Comment: Hi Tala & Zalp, Thank you for prompt reply. As Zalp mentioned, sleep and synchronised block added as testing. I tried without those first but got failed. For the iNum,iCurrSerl and icurtblseq is passed correctly. i put a debug on cardcreprocess method and it returns correct values. pro, prof, sBranch values which passed to getNextNo method is static variables but those are common for all.

Answer (score 0):

**This is wrong, read the comment. :) Leaving it due to consistency of the thread**

You sleep 1000ms in the thread. That is 1 second.

10000 inserts = 10000 seconds = 166 minutes.

You allow the thread pool 15 minutes to execute, then you shut it down.

Comment: `threadPool.awaitTermination(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)` returns true or false. No tasks are interrupted

Comment: Oops. Guess the not indented code got the best of me, I'll edit.